# Laravel Eloquent: How to store model values before saving?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a custom function within one of my models. It looks like this:

```
    public function newWithTeam($data, $team_id = false){

    $levels = Permissions::get_levels();

    $this->email    = $data['email'];
    $this->password = bcrypt($data['password']);
    $this->username = $data['username'];

    $this->save();

    $profile =  new Profile(['name' => $data['name'],'bio'  => $data['bio']]);
    $this->profile()->save($profile);
    }
```

Here, you can see I store the `email`, `password` and `username` as object properties, before hitting `save()`

Instead, I'd like to do this in one line, something like:

```
$this->store(['email' => $data['email], 'password' => $data['password], 'username' => $data['username']]);

$this->save();
```

I am aware that the `create()` method exists, but when I use this, the following line 
`$this->profile()->save($profile);` does not work properly. I think the `create()` function does not work the same as `save()` for some reason! **Is there any equivalent to the `store()` function as above?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method that You're looking for is `fill`:

```
$this->fill([
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password' => $data['password'],
    'username' => $data['username']]
);
$this->save();
```

You can use it for both creating and updating.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the **`fill()`** method to achieve what you are looking for.

But before using it, you should know a few things.

Laravel models are protected against mass-assignment by security reasons, to use the **`fill()`** method you will need to define what properties of your model can be filled using the **`fillable`** or the **`guarded`** properties.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserModel extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['email', 'password', 'username'];

    public function newWithTeam($data, $team_id = false){

        $levels = Permissions::get_levels();

        $this->fill([
            'email'    => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'username' => $data['username']
        ]);

        $this->save();

        $profile = new Profile([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'bio' => $data['bio']
        ]);

        $this->profile()->save($profile);
    }
}
```

The **`fillable`** property functions like a white-list for mass-assignment. If you want the other way, you can use the **`guarded`** property that will function like a black-list. Which means that every column listed within the **`guarded`** property will not be available for mass-assignment and everything else will, it's your choice.

About your last statement, if you look at the implementation of the **`create()`** method you will find that it accepts a regular php array, while the **`save()`** method will accept an Eloquent Model instance. That's why **`create()`** will not work receiving your **`$profile`** variable.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use fill directly:

```
$this->fill($data);
$this->save();
```

It will use the array keys as object attributes, so make sure you'll use the same.

Also, make sure you have set the $fillable in your model (http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment):

```
class x extends Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = ['email','password','username'];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100 % sure I understood you correctly, but it sounds like you want to make a oneliner update without screwing up the profile creation. In that case, you can simply use the `update()` method:

```
$this->update(['email' => $data['email], 'password' => bcrypt($data['password]), 'username' => $data['username']]);
```

That saves the new values for you.

Comment: I think he's creating rather than updating actually, could be wrong though!

Answer (score 0):

So what happens when you run `$this->create()`? Are you getting an error?

Consider that `create()` will return the new object that you created so you could try:

```
$user = $this->create([
    'email' => $data['email], 
    'password' => $data['password], 
    'username' => $data['username']
]);

$user->profile()->create([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'bio'  => $data['bio']
]);
```

Didn't test this so see how you get on and leave a comment if you have any further issues. Happy coding!